# how to avoid memory leakage from an animated GIF

Tags: java, android, animation, memory-leaks

I'm receiving URLs from server which should be translated to GIFs, These GIFs should animate whenever the user clicks on them or when receiving a response from any of the users, everything is working fine however when receiving lots of them I experience memory leakage, it doesn't go out of memory however the memory keeps increasing constantly and keeps facing hickups, please advise what can be done in order to avoid having them on the memory, I've tried initializing the animImageView with null however still the same attitude, please advise what can be done.

```
public void getGifts() {
    Communicator.getInstance().on("sendGift", new Emitter.Listener() {

        Animation anim;
        EmojiModel emojiUrl = new EmojiModel();
        String url = emojiUrl.getUrlFile();

        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            JSONDictionary response = (JSONDictionary) args[0];
            url = (String) response.get("giftUrl");

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    animImageView = null;
                    animImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                    animImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(url)
                            .thumbnail(0.1f)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .crossFade()
                            .override(900,400)
                            .into(animImageView);


                    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = 
                    (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageView_relative);
                    anim = 
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), 
            R.anim.move_to_right_anim);
                    relativeLayout.addView(animImageView);
                    animImageView.startAnimation(anim);

                    StreamActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            anim.setAnimationListener(new 
                            Animation.AnimationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
              anim =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), 
              R.anim.move_to_right_anim);
              animImageView.startAnimation(anim);
             }

             @Override
             public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                animImageView = null;
             }

             @Override
             public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                animImageView = null;
             }
           });
          }
        });
       }
      };
        mhandler.post(runnable);
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by adding relativeLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout(); before adding the view